# Laggy storyboard animation windows phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, storyboard, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using storyboard animations in my windows phone 8.1 app and i have a serious occasional lag problem. (Lumia 930)
Ohh also i guess i could add its an universal app template.

FIrst the animation code:

```XAML
 <Page.Resources>
    <local:SimpleMathConverter x:Key="SimpleMathConverter"/>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ImageViewShowAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="GameImageView">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ImageViewHideAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="GameImageView">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="90"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ResultViewShowAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="GameResutView">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="ResultViewHideAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="GameResutView">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-90"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then the code behind event handling

```C#
 public GamePage()
 {
    ImageViewHideAnimation.Completed += (sender, o) => ResultViewShowAnimation.Begin();
    ResultViewHideAnimation.Completed += (sender, o) => ImageViewShowAnimation.Begin();
 }
```

and the button invoking the animations

```C#
 private async void ChangeState()
 {
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher;
    switch (state)
    {
        case GameState.ImageView:

            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ImageViewHideAnimation.Begin());
            state = GameState.ResultView;
            break;
        case GameState.ResultView:
            await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => ResultViewHideAnimation.Begin());
            state = GameState.ImageView;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
 }
```

What this animation actually does is pretends that you flip a card and show the content on the other side, when u click the rotate the button again it reverses the card agian showing the initial content.
What the issue is that sometimes, i would say 4/10 it lags when the animation is supposed to start and actually displays half way through the animation. It's like the animation started but the screen hasn't caught up yet. I tried running animation with and without dispatcher hoping for some other effect but no. Any tips how can i angle this problem?

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the 1 sec to 90 degree thing, and instead input 10 separate key frames of 10 degree each?  I just want to see if that 1 sec is just way too fast for the phone to respond.

Comment: When i changed animation to 10 keyframes 0.1sec each and 10 degree change everything works fine. Thx for help. Do you know what is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, I will put my reasoning in a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you get rid of the 1 sec to 90 degree thing, and instead input 10 separate key frames of 10 degree each? I just want to see if that 1 sec is just way too fast for the phone to respond.

---

I think it doesn't pre-calculate/pre-render your transition.  So each time you're doing such a huge 90 degree turn it takes awhile for it to calculate each time.  Limiting it to several KeyFrames instead of one, eliminates/narrows the time needed for it to calculate thus showing your animation very quickly.